# Script to download gmail attachment without downloading all over again

Tags: google-apps-script, gdrive

I created an script that can transfer my gmail attachment to gdrive, but I have to modify my script since it downloads all the gmail attachment even its already downloaded.

May I know what I need to modify on my script?

```
function saveGmailToGdrive(){

  const folderId = "GDRIVE"

  const searchItem = "label:MONEY"

  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchItem,0,100)

  threads.forEach((thread) => {

    const messages = thread.getMessages()

    messages.forEach((message) => {
      
      const attachments = message.getAttachments({
        includeInlineImages:false,
        includeAttachments:true
      })

      attachments.forEach((attachment) => {

      Drive.Files.insert({
        title:attachment.getName(),
        mimeType:attachment.getContentType(),
        parents:[{id:folderId}]

      },

      attachment.copyBlob()
      )

      })
       
    })
  })




}
```

I hope someone can help me thank you!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether my proposed method is the direction you expect, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, how about storing the message IDs that the attachment files were downloaded? By this, after 2nd run of the script, the attachment files from only new messages can be downloaded by searching the message IDs.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please create a new Spreadsheet and put the Spreadsheet ID to `spreadsheetId`.

```js
function saveGmailToGdrive() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please create new Spreadsheet and put Spreadsheet ID here.

  // 1. Retrieve message IDs from Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const values = lastRow == 0 ? [] : sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow).getValues().map(([a]) => a);

  // 2. By checking the message IDs, the attachment files are downloaded.
  const folderId = "GDRIVE"; // Please set your folder ID.
  const searchItem = "label:MONEY";
  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchItem, 0, 100);
  const ids = threads.flatMap((thread) => {
    const messages = thread.getMessages();
    return messages.map((message) => {
      const id = message.getId();
      if (!values.includes(id)) {
        const attachments = message.getAttachments({ includeInlineImages: false, includeAttachments: true });
        attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
          Drive.Files.insert({ title: attachment.getName(), mimeType: attachment.getContentType(), parents: [{ id: folderId }] }, attachment.copyBlob());
        });
      }
      return [id];
    });
  });

  // 3. Update message IDs on Spreadsheet.
  if (ids.length == 0) return;
  sheet.clear().getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, ids.length, 1).setValues(ids);
}
```

- When this script is run for the first time, the attachment files are downloaded from all messages. In this run, the message IDs are stored in Spreadsheet. After 2nd run, by searching the message IDs, the attachment files are downloaded.

#### Reference:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Thank you for your modification it works! may I know if do we have option that we don't have to use spreedsheet?

Comment: @rodskies Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad the script works. First, I had thought to use the script property. But I thought that the size of script properties might be small for a database. So, I proposed to use Spreadsheet as a database. For example, in your situation, as a simple method, I think that a text file can be also used as a database for storing the message IDs.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help and inputs. I learn a lot. cheers!